# MQ Casting error when publishing after upgrading to ServiceStack v4

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Since upgrading to ServiceStack v4, my code for adding an object to a Redis MQ now throws a casting exception.

Code (that hasn't changed):

```
mqClient.Publish(new Message<myRequest>(new myRequest(Id)) {
     Priority = 1
});
```

Exception that is thrown:

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'ServiceStack.Messaging.Message`1[XXX.XXX.MyRequest]' to type 
'ServiceStack.Messaging.IMessage`1[ServiceStack.Messaging.Message`1[XXX.XXX.MyRequest]]'.
```

I'm pretty sure the guidance on the Github wiki hasn't changed for v4, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Please advise!

Thanks.

Comment: I can't repro this. Are you using the latest v4.0.11 for all packages?

Comment: I was on v4.0.10. I've upgraded to v4.0.11 and problem has gone away. Thanks